# How can I get initial reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I have been using Stack Overflow for a long time. But I am not able to upvote any of the answers or questions because I need to have a minimum of 15 reputation to do so.

Most of the questions I have, have already been asked on Stack Overflow and I find relevant answers. So, how does a new Stack Overflow user get his/her initial reputation?

Comment: Start by following the rules and posting on-topic questions.

Comment: new users can't participate in meta...

Comment: I think it is a good thing that you don't want to clutter up the site with likely duplicate questions and hurried answers. You are getting a pile of downvotes right now, but don't let that discourage you. Don't feel pressured into cluttering up the site. Take your time and think things through, perhaps your nature anyway. Note that beneath good answers (and maybe questions), there is a prompt, 'Was this helpful to you?'. In the days when I myself couldn't upvote, I clicked on this every time. I don't know how that is recorded or if it's used (no one seems to know), but it is atleast something.

Comment: There is a lot of info on meta.se like [How does reputation work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: I would start with reading through the faq/help center to learn what the site is about, and what we expect from questions and answers and all the other stuff, and then just do it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, but what if they aren't a new user, have read all of the faqs and rules, and have been around a while? What if it is because of this knowledge that they are not cluttering up the site duplicate questions and hurried answers?

Comment: @ouflak: Then you are at the "just do it" step.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, well that's sort of the point. By visiting regularly, and not cluttering up the site, they are 'just doing it', and doing it correctly.

Comment: @ouflak: And how is that bad for anyone?

Comment: If an established no-rep user comes across a good answer/question that helps them, they might want to upvote it. They can't. As I pointed out in my in comment above, they do get a 'Was this helpful to you?' prompt. So that's something I guess. But does the OP actually ever know of this feedback? In fact, is this used anywhere or even noted? The life-blood of this website isn't just questions and answers, it's feedback. And established no-rep users don't have a visible means of participating. Have you ever gotten a message that somebody found your question/answer 'helpful'? I sure haven't.

Comment: Sorry your question has been labeled a duplicate. I guess that, for right now anyway, there just isn't going to be any consideration for users who have been around the site for a long time, used it in a positive way, but have no reputation. Maybe as StackExchange matures and such users become more of a force, this type of issue will be re-visited. Anyway congrats on your first +10. Guess you can participate in Meta now! Woohoo!

Comment: @ouflak: I have. A lot of my answers have this accepted checkmark, which means "this was helpful". And the barrier to do things like comment up and dowvote aren't high. Just participate, suggest a few *good* edits and you are with it, even if you dont answer or ask questions.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Sorry. Guess I assumed that most people know about this feature, especially since I'd seen it for so long when I first came upon StackOverflow. When you don't have enough rep to vote on an answer, you will be presented with a grayed out prompt, "Was this helpful to you" beneath an answer. It's been a while, but I believe you can click 'Yes' and then it disappears. It is safe to say the vast majority of users who peruse through this site will never actually bother going through the process of registering and trying to get rep. But the question remains, what happens to that feedback?

Comment: @ouflak: "This kind of issue" it simply is not an "issue" as it isn't hard to gain a little of reputation, as noted in answeres here and in the duplicate. Reputation -- just like in the real world -- can not and should not be gained just by hanging around for a while, but by showing that you are a good stackizen by doing any of the good things that gain you reputation here. And there is nothing what prevents a new users from getting reputation, it may just not be as fast as in the good old days

Comment: Actually I am somewhat active on a site where 'reputation' is gained by participating in ways that don't have to do with publishing or editing (CodeProject). But this was question wasn't labeled a 'Not an Issue'. It was labeled as a duplicate, which it really isn't. Further it does actually address a relevant issue here on StackOverflow, how to get feedback from longtime users of the site who don't have enough reputation to vote up or down. The only means that I'm familiar with is that 'helpful' prompt. And I don't know how useful that really is.

Comment: The irony here is delicious.

Answer (score 43):

> How to get initial reputation on Stack Overflow?

Simple question, simple answer:

### Post good questions and answers!

Seriously, that's all there is to it. Sure, there are other ways to earn reputation, like suggesting edits, but that's not really the point. This is a Q&A site: our lifeblood is questions and answers. We need people to ask good, [on-topic *questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and we need people to post useful *answers* to those questions.

Because that's so important, we give you reputation for doing so: +10 reputation points for upvotes on a question or an answer.

And trust me, if you post good questions and answers, *you will get upvotes*. You might get a couple of downvotes along the way—everyone does, it's nothing to get worked up about. The upvotes more than make up for the difference, if you're following our guidelines. That's how everyone here earned their reputation, and you can do exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's true (+1) and it's what can be found in *Tour* and *Help Center*, but wouldn't it make also sense to [encourage specialization](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261095/2932052), I found that [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is underestimated compared to the ["original"](http://stackoverflow.com/), especially by programmers ;).

Answer (score 20):

**Start specialized.**

Chose one of the [more specialized sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) of the Stack Exchange network, look for **an area you feel really comfortable with** (for instance poker, travelling, parenting). Earn your first 200 rep there, and you'll get the [*site association bonus: +100*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) on each site you are registered on, and also those you register in future.

Stack Overflow itself is pretty hectic this time...

Answer (score 8):

Here are your options to gain the 15 reputation needed to upvote:

1. Earn two upvotes on one or more answers.
2. Earn two upvotes on one or more questions.
3. Have eight suggested edits approved.
4. Earn an accepted checkmark on one answer.

Or any combination of the above.

Comment: All the while not doing anything "stupid" to get yourself downvoted and have to start this brutal process all over again. :)

Comment: You forgot that you have initial 1 rep. point, so it is "**7** suggested edits approved". Also you gain 10 reputation for upvoted article and 2 for accepting an answer, to be complete. I can't edit this answer to correct it. Maybe the fastest way would be 1 answer upvote + 2 suggested edits as it was in my case, but this is subjective.