# "top overall" ranking statements can also have a depressing effect

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, user-interface, top-users

Out of sheer curiosity, I found user profiles with "top 100% overall" in the reputation header (in summary view). I don't know how often this occurs.<sup>[*]</sup>

[image: 200 Reputation -- top 100% overall]

The "depressing effect" doesn't affect new users, because the display usually starts with *top ...% this week*, but it's the **bad "welcome again" after pausing some time**.

My question: Does it really help to display top-rankings *exclusively* according the 200-points criterion?

Wouldn't some threshold, say 50%, be a good idea?

---

*Edit-Summaries:*

- This problem doesn't affect users when they break the 200-rep barrier, so it's especially not an issue for "new users", I **changed title** and **added some text** to clarify this.
- I clarified that I don't report a sporadic accident.

<sup>[*]</sup> you can try finding similar examples by starting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=5000&tab=reputation&filter=all)

Comment: Could you mention the other factors you would like to see taken into account?

Comment: This is actually pretty funny. But [today I learned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261079/how-to-get-initial-reputation-in-stackoverflow#comment45515_261085) that I am a sociopath because I downvote posts on Meta, so maybe I'm not a good one to judge.

Comment: @Cody, more power to you. How people can infer someone that spends their time *helping others* is a *sociopath* is beyond me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the percentage itself, wouldn't 50% be a good threshold?

Comment: @Wolf, well, apart from artificially limiting the range would that really change anything? 50% will become the new "tail" of the list, and once users realize that they will be as depressed as when they were stuck at 100%, won't they?

Comment: I was under the impression that there already was a threshold. My only really active account is SO, but I have a few other SE accounts lurking around, but SO is the only one where I see a 'Top X%' label.

Comment: @NickJ it's exactly the 200-rep-threshold, your top-ranking is currently shown for SO because [only there](http://stackexchange.com/users/1321290/nickj?tab=accounts) you have 200+

Comment: @CodyGray I had to change the title again (somewhat back), because it's def. not a new-users problem

Comment: The phrase "top 100%" does sound odd, "bottom 1%" would be better

Comment: @PeterJ ...more understandable, but even more depressing ;)

Comment: @CodyGray Not only am I a sociopath for downvoting, It seems I am a psychopath because I vote to close as well!

Comment: What am I missing here?

Comment: @CodyGray There is nothing wrong with down voting on meta, it does not affect that users reputation on the main site, I would take that with a grain of salt. Although I think it's a good idea for users  to vote in the same way as they would in SO.

Comment: I can see how it might affect users, although reputation is just artificial. It in no ways means you are inferior because yours is low or you have high down votes. My two first to post on meta (in which I thought was well thought out and good quality questions) both have high down-votes. But that was disagreement and does not mean it was poor and low quality question (err I hope). Basically low reputation isn't something to take personally.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek `I can see how it might affect users...` if this refers to my question: I don't address meta sites here, and I think users with 200+ already added some value to the site, so they should not be demotivated after having a break.

Comment: Yes but this demotivation is based on how the user takes it. The site also can give you different data representation to make you feel better. Such as **Top 4% this week** or **Top 6% this month**, even if you may be **top 90%+ overall**. In which I think is a good idea.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek well-known: the most optimistic ranking is shown.

Comment: Still this feature, that I think it is "bad feature", is in-use. At some cases a user can be in the first page out of 50 pages. But he is top 100%! The equation should really consider how many users and how many points there are. It should depend on an equation rather than a fixed number (the 200 rigid threshold)

Answer (score 6):

What about using [CSS3 opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)? It has a fuzziness that fits well here.

```
* top 10% overall <span style="opacity: .90;">top 10% overall</span>
* top 30% overall <span style="opacity: .70;">top 30% overall</span>
* top 50% overall <span style="opacity: .50;">top 50% overall</span>
* top 70% overall <span style="opacity: .30;">top 70% overall</span>
* top 90% overall <span style="opacity: .10;">top 90% overall</span>
```

[image]