# How can I post to Meta on Stack Exchange Stack Overflow to accomplish my next badge?

Tags: support, meta, privileges

My next badge award recommended by this site is for "participate in Meta" in order to increase my reputation points.

But it then says you need "5 reputation points" to ask a question on the Meta site.

How can I complete my next badge and get off 3 reputation points when the minimum points to complete the accomplishment requires 5 points?

I clicked the link to complete my next badge on this site and was unable to do what was asked.

Comment: You can participate in ways other than asking questions. One way to gain rep (on Stack Overflow as well as Meta) is by answering questions. Adding comments is also a way to participate, and once you have reached the rep requirement for voting, you can participate that way, too. If the badge you're interesting in gaining is specific to Meta participation, try reading existing Meta posts, add a comment or answer a question on Meta. [Ths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) might be a good place to start.

Comment: While I've migrated your question here, I wouldn't recommend this as a general strategy to get a post onto MSO. Having said that, where do you see "participate in Meta" as a badge? The [badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) has two meta-related badges: [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) and [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) neither of which seem to be exactly what you're describing.

Comment: @HenryEcker I believe they're referring to [the "Next privilege" UI in the profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwTs2.png).

Comment: Oh, well that makes more sense @Ryan. I was focusing too much on the word "badge" I guess.

Comment: Note that badges do not have impact on reputation.

Comment: [/help/whats-reputation](/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Forget about badges suggestions. It is usually some random nonsense. You will earn them naturally as you use the site.

Comment: You don’t earn reputation by earning a badge. Earn a different badge until you have the necessary reputation to participate in the meta community

Comment: You need 5 rep so go get 5 rep, I don't understand the question.

Comment: My view of badges is culturally inappropriate.

Comment: ... I'm confused. You've had the account for **more than 10 years**? But apparently have only just started to use it for anything (first main site question asked Aug 2), or to try to understand anything about how the site works? ...You remembered your password that whole time, though?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [Remember the classics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JNGI1dI-e8)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel everytime i click to answer an question or post a comment anywhere it has never let me so i just gave up - i took a few minutes to actually write something now -  i am probably not the only person - they can't comment on this thread to chime  in LOL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My next badge award recommended by this site is for "participate in Meta" in order to increase my reputation points.

No, you got it backwards. You need reputation (5 points) in order to participate on meta, not the other way around.

Also, note that there isn't a badge named "participate in Meta". You can see a list of all badges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). What you saw there is your next [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), not badge. That's why it requires a certain reputation threshold to be met.

---

#### Useful posts:

- [How can I get initial reputation on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261079/how-can-i-get-initial-reputation-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)